# JavaBeans vs. ActiveX: Strategic analysis

Tags: java, distributed-computing, com

JavaBeans and ActiveX both serve the same basic function: to facilitate communication among software components within framework "containers." These containers include Web browsers and other document viewers. [Courtesy](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077606/client-side-java/javabeans-vs--activex--strategic-analysis.html)

---

ActiveX controls and JavaBeans have a great deal in common. In fact, it’s not too challenging to map the interfaces provided by one into those defined by the other, and both Microsoft and Sun offer software today that does this. The most important distinction between them is that ActiveX controls are nearly always Intel binaries running only on Windows and Windows NT, while JavaBeans can potentially run on many systems. [Courtesy](http://www.davidchappell.com/writing/article_ActiveX_v_JavaBean.php)

---

Basically I am a Java and JavaScript developer, trying to understand the ActiveXObject term.

I had investigated a lot about ActiveX but still not clear.
I have compared protocol and technologies a lot to understand the ActiveX term,
like RMI vs DCOM, ASP vs Servlet, ActiveX(COM) vs JavaBean and so on.

at last(hope) What I understand:

> ActiveX helps to communicate application with each other in windows.

**Is my assumption right?**